# Incomplete profile

Tags: feature-request

Trying to give the best answer to a people's question, I spend most of the time to choose at what level should be this answer usefull for this specific people.

What I'm doing frequently is to refer to his profile, in order to gather informations at least for the knowledge background, the real job description and the experience.

Unfortunatelly (and it is common_ that this informations are not in the profile. So I can not understand why this forum it is not free and need a regidtrtion (I can understand well some safety and stastical purpose etc reasons).

So I place the next proposal to the administrators board: New members of EE should complete their profile as accurate as possible about their knowledge background, the real job and the experience they have until now. Also old member must be update their profile.

Answer (score 4):

I can see where you're coming from but Electrical Engineering is part of the Stack Exchange network and I think this would have to be a network wide policy rather than anything EE moderators could do anything about. Here's an example of the profile of [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) who is a Stack Overflow user with a reputation close to 600k:

> I love writing code and I am really passionate about it.

So by asking old members to update their profile you'd be asking people like that who've made an amazing contribution to add additional information they might not want to share. For new users or really anyone asking questions a few things come to mind:

- It's easy to range from expert to novice in various aspects of something as broad as EE or programming on SO.
- People either straight out lie about their experience or over / under-estimate their abilities in certain areas.

The better way in my opinion is for the OP to state in the question what level of experience they have in that particular area if it's important to the question and where they are stuck. Comments are for clarifying that sort of thing when it's not provided initially if you can't judge it from the original question.

If they don't respond the goal of Stack Exchange is to form a repository of questions and answers useful for future visitors, so then it become a judgement call of whether it's worth answering for future visitors. If so I'd just write an answer appropriate for anyone you think might be searching for answer to a similar question.